# Find x-axis location to make an element move

Tags: javascript, keypress, x-axis

I'm trying to make an element move backward on the X axis when the user presses "a". However, I don't know how to make it move farther every time the users presses that key :(. I'm new to JS

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  let moveBy = 20;
  if (e.key === "a") {
    moveBy++;
    element.style.webkitTransform = `translateX(-${moveBy}px)`;
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: this isn't working ?

Comment: Vugar Taghiyev's answer works! Thank you ^__^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define moveBy outside of function and increment every keypress

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div');
  let moveBy = 20;

document.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "a") {
    moveBy++;
    element.style.webkitTransform = `translateX(-${moveBy}px)`;
    moveBy+=20
  }
})
```

```css
div {

width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```